# Keeping the tab focus inside a jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently learning jQuery dialog and would like to use it in my side project. I want to add tabindex to the divs in the dialog for tabbing. But the focus goes elsewhere when I tab on the last element in the dialog.

I want the focus to go back to the first element when I tab on the last element. Is there a way to keep the focus in the dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Add a keypress event on the last element to ignore the default tab action and put the focus back on the first element in the dialog.

The following example assumes the last element is `last_element_id` and the first is `first_element_id`.

```
$('#last_element_id').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 9) {
        $('#first_element_id').focus();    
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Using `e.which` is sufficient since jQuery already normalizes this for us.

Answer (score 0):

Disable tabbing on any elements you want to skip like this:

```
$("#element").attr("tabIndex", -1);
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is when the dialog is closed, all those elements that have been changed to tabindex -1 will no longer be tabbable.  So if there's a form below the dialog, it'll no longer function the same way as before the dialog was opened.

Answer (score 0):

Any negative tab index should stop the element from being focused so just negate the existing value and then remove the minus when putting the element back into the tab order.

**e.g.** change a tab index from 10 to -10 and then back to 10